# Are there any problems to expect when you add a MOSFET to a DC/DC converter to add PWM modulation for LED brightness regulation?

Tags: mosfet, pwm, dc-dc-converter, led-driver, switching-regulator

I need to power LEDs from a solar powered setup with a 12V battery, around 25W of power.
I want to be able to dim the LEDs using a microcontroller.

I was not able to find a reasonably priced DC/DC converter that also has a PWM input. Most only have a potentiometer if they are dimmable.

Can I just add a MOSFET to the output of the regulator to dim the LEDs using PWM or are there any problems to expect because the regulator itself is already a switching supply?

The model i was thinking about using is the Mean Well RSD-30G-12.

Comment: You need to show a schematic of what you propose. Have you tried to simulate it?

Comment: Difficult to simulate a off the shelf powersupply, maybe try with just any model of a switching supply? The idea is really just to take an n-channel MOSFET and switch the output of the powersupply with it.

Comment: between which components do you want to put the converter?

Comment: Your approach is correct; PWMing an entire DC/DC converter isn't recommended.  Use a MOSFET to switch the load and let the converter do its thing.  Add inductors and/or capacitors in series/parallel with the load as necessary.

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll try it out.